# помогите с формой. Не отправляется заявка на почту

Tags: php

`

```
<?php
$fio = $_POST['name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$fio = htmlspecialchars($fio);
$phone = htmlspecialchars($phone);
$fio = urldecode($fio);
$phone = urldecode($phone);
$fio = trim($fio);
$phone = trim($phone);
$VISIT_TYPES = [
  'standard' => 2000,
  'consultation' => 5000
];
$requested_visit_type = $_POST['visit_type'];
if(in_array($requested_visit_type, array_keys($VISIT_TYPES), true)) {
    header('Location: https://money.yandex.ru/to/410015106353027/' + $VISIT_TYPES[$requested_visit_type]);
    mail("e-prohorov-2000@yandex.ru", "Заявка с сайта", "Имя: ".$fio.".\n Телефон: ".$phone.".\n Заплатил:" .$VISIT_TYPES[$requested_visit_type] , "From: e-prohorov-2000@yandex.ru \r\n");
}   else {
    echo 'Неподдерживаемый вариант посещения!';
}
?>
```

```
<html>
<form action="mail.php" method="post" id="backmail" style="max-width: 420px; margin:0 auto;">
              <p class="text">Выберите вариант посещения:</p>
              <label>
                <input class="radio" type="radio" name="visit_type" value="standard">
                <span class="radio-custom rtext"></span>
                <span class="label rtext"><b>2000 руб.</b> - стандартное посещение курса</span>
              </label>
              <label>
                <input class="radio" type="radio" name="visit_type" value="consultation">
                <span class="radio-custom"></span>
                <span class="label rtext" style="position: relative;top: 12px;"><b>5000 руб.</b> - посещение курса + 1 час <br>личной консультации спикера</span>
              </label>

              <div class="input">
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Ваше имя*" required><br>
                <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Ваш телефон*" required>
                <button type="submit" class="sendmail">Записаться</button>
              </div>
            </form>
</html>
```

`

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы подобный код работал нужно, чтобы ещё сам сервер был настроен.

Функция `mail`, которую вы используете требует установленного sendmail, postfix или какого-либо другого почтового сервера. Если вы пользуетесь shared-хостингом, то ваш хостер может не предоставлять подобные сервисы или включать по заявке (обращайтесь в техподдержку вашего провайдера). Если у вас собственный VPS/VDS (есть пароль на root), то гуглите статьи о настройке серверов типа "Как настроить отправку почты средствами php-функции mail"

Альтернативно, вы можете не использовать функцию `mail` (она идёт в составе самого PHP), а использовать различные *мейлеры* -- это код (пакеты), который можно подключить к своему коду и использовать их функции отправки почты.
Как правило в мейлерах есть не только режимы работы с локальными почтовыми серверами, но и возможность отправки через удалённый почтовый сервер типа yandex или gmail. Это как раз удобно тем, кто не имеет доступа к конфигурированию php.ini и/или настройке самого сервера.

Примеры мейлеров в php: phpmailer или swiftmailer